# Swapping elements in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have the following list of lists-

```
[['s1','s2','s3','s4'],
 ['s5','s6','s7','s8'],
 ['s9','s10','s11','s12']]
```

I want to make the list into-

```
[['s1s3','s2s4'],
 ['s5s7','s6s8'],
 ['s9s11','s10s12']]
```

The lists within the list can contain more than 4 elements but it always contains even number of elements. Is there a general way of doing this without using two `for` loops? I'm using nested loops at the moment to do this and I want to avoid nested loops.

Comment: Is the structure of the list fixed?

Comment: For the inside list `['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6']` the output should be `['s1s3s5','s2s4s6']` or `['s1s4','s2s5','s3s6']`?

Comment: As you have list of lists, no, you cannot do it better than with two loops.

Comment: Not sure what you have now but you probably can't get much faster than `[[''.join(i[::2]), ''.join(i[1::2])] for i in obj]` where `obj` is your nested list.  Also, unclear how you'd like to treat sublists with 6+ elements.

Comment: @MaximTitarenko It should be ['s1s4','s2s5','s3s6']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

After seeing a comment the OP made about the result desired from a row with:

```
['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6']
```

being:

```
 ['s1s4','s2s5','s3s6']
```

The code below has been modified accordingly (and should work in both Python 2 and 3).

---

Here's a general way to do it, but it effectively still uses nested loops since there's one in the `pairwise()` helper function:

```
from itertools import islice

data = [['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6'],
        ['s7','s8','s9','s10'],
        ['s11','s12']]

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> [s0+s2, s1+s3), s3+s5, ...]"
    a = iter(iterable)
    b = islice(iterable, len(iterable)//2, None)
    return [''.join(pair) for pair in zip(a, b)]

data2 = [pairwise(row) for row in data]
print(data2)  # -> [['s1s4', 's2s5', 's3s6'], ['s7s9', 's8s10'], ['s11s12']]
```

Comment: Umm... `iterable[2:]` just makes me shiver a bit... If anything `b = islice(iterable, 2, None)` kind of keeps consistent

Comment: @JonClements: Yeah, probably should have named the argument `indexable`... Good suggestion, I'll fix my answer. Thanks.

Comment: What if inside list contains more than 4 elements, which is a valid input as the OP mentioned?

Comment: @MaximTitarenko: This should properly handle any row (or as you said "inside list") with an even number of elements.

Comment: @martineau, please check the input like  `data = [['s1','s2','s3','s4','55','66'],['s5','s6','s7','s8'],['s9','s10','s11','s12']]` or  `data = [['s1','s2','s3','s4','55','66'],['s5','s6','s7','s8','77','88'],['s9','s10','s11','s12','99','00']]`. It seems like the output will be not the one that is required

Comment: @martineau `b = islice(iterable, 2, None)` has to be `b = islice(iterable, int(len(iterable)/2), None)`

Comment: @Misha, and  `... len(iterable)//2` for Python 3

Comment: @Maxim: With `data = [['s1','s2','s3','s4','55','66'],['s5','s6','s7','s8'],['s9'‌​,'s10','s11','s12']]` the results is `[['s1s3', 's2s4', 's355', 's466'], ['s5s7', 's6s8'], ['s9s11', 's10s12']]` which is what I would expect and is correct I believe (or is at least what I intended). Don't understand what you and the OP are talking about regarding using half the length as the second argument (the `len(iterable)//2`). When three arguments are given, [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) interprets them to be the _iterable_, _start_, & _stop_ values.

Comment: @martineau, the OP's goal (as it follows from his comment below the question) is to combine the corresponding elements from the 1st and 2nd half of each inner list. Therefore the desired convertation for `['s1','s2','s3','s4','55','66']` is `['s1s4','s255','s366']`.

Comment: @Maxim: Yeah, I just noticed that comment under the question. Very roundabout way to provide it. Would have been better if it had been added to the question so the important detail couldn't be missed...

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension will work for you. Check the solution below. I have not optimized it but it works

```
lis = [['s1','s2','s3','s4'],
       ['s5','s6','s7','s8'],
       ['s9','s10','s11','s12']
       ]  
new_list = [["".join([odd_value for count, odd_value in enumerate(each_list) if count % 2 == 0]),"".join([odd_value for count, odd_value in enumerate(each_list) if count % 2 == 1])] for each_list in lis ]

print(new_list)
```

Comment: check it with the input: `lis = [['s1','s2','s3','s4', 's5', 's6'],['s7','s8','s9','s10','s11', 's12'],['s13','s14','s15','s16', 's17', 's18']]` and note that the OP mentioned that `['s1','s2','s3','s4', 's5', 's6']` should be converted to `['s1s4','s2s5','s3s6']`

Comment: maybe I didnot understand your question. Thought you needed to seperate odd and even values.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this can be implemented with just one explicit `for-loop`:

```
lst =  [['s1','s2','s3','s4', 's5', 's6'],
        ['d1','d2','d3','d4', 'd5', 'd6']]

# res = [map(lambda x,y: x+y, l[:len(l)//2], l[len(l)//2:]) for l in lst] # Python 2
res = [list(map(lambda x,y: x+y, l, l[len(l)//2:])) for l in lst] # Python 3

print(res) # [['s1s4', 's2s5', 's3s6'], ['d1d4', 'd2d5', 'd3d6']]
```

But this is just syntactic sugar, because there is an implicit 2nd `for-loop` inside `map`.